# passing form value into php without submitting the form

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am building a step by step form. At the first step, people enter their email. Then after they clicked next step, it gets the security question from database.

Here is the problem, is it possible to get data from database without submitting the from? I found people used AJAX. I am new to it. like i have the first step code here:

```
<div>
step 1

<input type='text' name='email' id='email' maxlength="50" />

nextstepbutton goes here

</div>
```

and this is step 2 code:

```
<div>
step 2
<label><?php echo getSecurityQuestion($emailvalue) ?></label>
</div>
```

How can I pass the value of 'email' into `$emailvalue`?

Comment: Have you read any [Ajax tutorials](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=ajax+tutorial)?

Comment: Can you fix this so you're actually asking a question that requires more than a "Yes" answer?

Answer (score 1):

give your next button an id. Then say if you're using jquery you could do something along the lines of

```
$('#next-button').click(function () {
  $.get('filename.php', { action: 'get_security_question', email: $('#email').val() }, function (data) {
    $('#security_question').val(data['message']);
  });
});
```

over in your php something like

```
if ($_GET['action'] === 'get_security_question') return "Here's your question for {$_GET['email']}.";
```

That is very vague and just a general outline but should give you an idea of how it kinda works.

Comment: I couldnt get the result. Can I ask what's: $('#security_question').val(data['message']);

Comment: @AlexChen read more about jQuery to understand what this answer is.

Comment: "$('#security_question').val(data['message']);" says to set the value of the element with id 'security_question' to the value of data['message'].

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do it without a form but you would have to use AJAX eg:

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" maxLength="50" />

<input type="button" value="Send" onClick="submitEmail()" />
```

You would need a JS function like:

```
function submitEmail(){

  var emailAdd = document.getElementByID("email").value ;

  // here you would hook into whatever ajax httprequest method you prefer

}
```